# RoboBrowser BadRequestKeyError(key)

Tags: python-3.x, werkzeug, robobrowser

I am trying to sign in to a website using RoboBrowser and I am stuck with a error message.

My code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser()

def login():
    browser.open('https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html')
    form = browser.get_form(id="login-form")
    form.fields["LoginEmailOrNickname"].value = "an_email_address"
    form.fields["login-password"].value = "a_password"
    form.fields["login-rememberMe"].value = "true"
    browser.submit_form(form)

login()
```

The error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rojaslee/Desktop/kijiji_poster/kijiji_poster.py", line 16, in <module>
    login()
  File "/home/rojaslee/Desktop/kijiji_poster/kijiji_poster.py", line 11, in login
    form.fields["LoginEmailOrNickname"].value = ["an_email_address"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 744, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
    werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Nobody?  Should I be asking this question in a different forum?  Thanks

Comment: hey did you find the solution??

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I've been struggling with the same problem. This worked for me:

```
from robobrowser import Robobrowser

browser = RoboBrowser

def login():
    browser.open('https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html')
    form = browser.get_form(id="login-form")
    form["EmailOrNickname"].value = "an_email_address"
    form["password"].value = "a_password"
    form["rememberMe"].value = "checked"
    browser.submit_form(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code from the web site you want to log in is as follows:

```
<section>
  <label for="LoginEmailOrNickname">Email Address or Nickname:</label>
  <input id="LoginEmailOrNickname" name="emailOrNickname" req="req" type="text" value="" maxlength="128"><span class="field-message" data-for="LoginEmailOrNickname"></span>
</section>
<section>
  <label for="login-password">Password:</label>
  <input id="login-password" name="password" req="req" type="password" value="" maxlength="64"><span class="field-message" data-for="login-password"></span>
  <a id="LoginForgottenPassword" href="/t-forgot-password.html">Forgot your password?</a>
</section>
```

To put a value on the form fields you have to get the **name** attribute, not the id.

This code should work:

```
form.fields["emailOrNickname"].value = "an_email_address"
form.fields["password"].value = "a_password"
form.fields["rememberMe"].value = "true"
```

If you need to get the fields of the form you can print them:

```
print form.fields
```

Answer (score 0):

But have you tried using a 'try and except'?

I was able to get around this error using:

```
try:
    form['userid'] = 'my_username'
    form['password'] = 'my_password'
except Exception:
    pass
```

I used a different website than you so make sure you input the correct form fields.

let me know if this helps!